# CSS: Selector for a text that is not within a span tag

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following DOM structure:

```
<label>
    <select>
    ...
    </select>
    records at one one time
</label>
```

Now, I intend to hide the text `records at one time` if the web page is viewed inside a mobile based browser using media queries.

My question is how can I select the text here? Note that this DOM is automatically generated  by a library (DataTables) and I have no control over it so adding a span class is not  possible. I wish that for mobile browsers, only the select be shown and not the `records at one time` - how can achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such selector in CSS. Selectors can only select elements or pseudo-elements, and there is no pseudo-element that would help here.

You can, however, hide the text with CSS, if the `label` element contains only the `select` element and the text to be hidden. You would hide the `label` element and “unhide” the `select` element. You cannot use `display: none`, since it hides all children. But there are other ways.

Perhaps the simplest is this:

```
label { visibility: hidden;}
select { visibility: visible; }
```

You can alternatively set the font size to zero and then the desired font size on the `select` element:

```
label { font-size: 0; }
select { font-size: 12pt; }
```

Unfortunately, you need to set the font size in physical units here (or use the `rem` unit, but its browser support is still limited).

Some browsers have a setting for minimal font size, but it does not seem to apply to a zero font size.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
label {
   font-size: 0;
}
label p {
   font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: `p` can be replaced with `select`

Answer (score -2):

I will take this HTML as an example:

```
<label>
    <p class="test">This is a test</p>
    records at one one time
</label>
```

It's really depend on what kind of styling you want to apply. As long as it does not affect [box-model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html) of the element you can do it by applying a default css style for your label which will affect both text with and without p tag:

```
label {
    color:red;
}
```

Then you can override the text within p tag using:

```
label p {
    color:yellow;
}
```

Now you can see that only text without p tag has red color.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LrNeN/)

Comment: How does this hide the text?